I want HMILabel1 display hexadecimal
library： PascalSCADA HCI
Control ： TCP_UDPPort1 -> ModBusTCPDriver1 -> PLCTagNumber1 -> HMILabel1
I want HMILabel1 display hexadecimal.

Convert your data to hex string manually and add that to the HMILabel

HMILabel does not support what you want.
Although it can display and format numeric values (see its NumberFormat property), the formatting is limited to what FormatFloat() can output, and it can't output numbers in hexadecimal, only in decimal and scientific notation.
